# Conditional Statement with CallBack Not Fireing

Tags: javascript, callback, conditional-statements, zepto

I have a basic conditional statement that has a chaining function. After the else method there is a callback of show() that doesn't fire.

What do I have wrong? Syntax??

Thnx

```
var closeList = $('#west');

    $('#menuToggle').click(function(){
        var p = $('#west').css('display');
        if (p != "block") {
            $('#contentBox').width('70%', function() {
                $('#west').show(); // <--THIS DOESNT FIRE!!
            });
        } else {
            $('#west').hide();
            $('#contentBox').width('98%');
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<!-- ------------------------- Main Content -------------------- -->
    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapperPosition">

        <div id="west">
        </div>

        <div id="contentBox">
            <div id="content" class="contentPosition"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @ RubbleFord  I did but I dont see how it matters - everything else works.  Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call them in sequence rather than with a callback:

```
if (p != "block") {
    $('#contentBox').width('70%');
    $('#west').show();
}
```

The issue is that [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2) doesn't have an option that accepts both a value and a function, only one or the other:

```
.width( value )
.width( function(index, width) )
```

So, pairing it with a value means the function will be ignored.

---

To elaborate on my comment:

```
if ($('#west').is(':hidden')) {
    $('#contentBox').width('70%');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#west').show();
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thnx, but that causes the content box to move off stage then back on.  No matter what order I do the show(), it fires first causing the contentBox to go off stage and then goes to the posision I want it.

Comment: @Andaero If you need to delay the `show` slightly, use `setTimeout` with a small timeout: `setTimeout(function () { $('#west').show(); }, 10);`. Also, what is the condition testing, exactly? Whether or not `#west` is hidden? If so, try `if ($('#west').is(':hidden'))` instead. (see edit for updated code)

Comment: Thnx!! Totallt forgot about the setTimeout function.